# Should I use comparative adj or superlative adj in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

What is "larger" size of this blouse? 
What is "the largest" size of this blouse?

Comment: Pretty much any context can be imagined for the use of any sentence or grammatical point. So we really need to know in what context do you want to say what. In general, if you want to refer to the 'superlative' size,  use *largest.*

Comment: Hello CarSmack!  This sentence is from an examination paper. It asks me to fill out the blanks. What is _____________ size of this blouse?  (large)  So, that's why I am asking for help. The answer is "the largest" on the answer sheet. But if I write "larger", should it be ok???

Comment: If the answer sheet says *the largest* is correct, why would you want to use ***the** larger*? Either one *could* be correct  depending upon the context . Usually a test will tell you what it is testing you on (for example, the comparative or superlative). I can say that either *larger* or *largest* by itself would not be standard English. Also, in English we fill *in* the blanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, "What is larger size" is not grammatical. You can say "Is there A larger size?" (comparative) or "What is THE NEXT larger size?" (comparative) or, as the answer sheet suggests, "What is the largest size?" (superlative). Of course, in real life, you might more likely say "Is THIS the largest size you have?" (meaning "Don't you have anything larger?") because you usually don't actually want to know what is the largest size, but rather whether they have one large enough to fit you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer must be "largest". :)
"Larger" means comparing two objects. Since the sentence is not comparing to another blouse, so it must be "largest".

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it depends. If you want just immediate larger size of the particular blouse, then "larger" is the word. And if you want the biggest size in that blouse, then obviously "largest" should be used.

Comment: Actually, "the next larger" would indicate the "immediate larger size" you mentioned"